# Conditional formatting on 4th entry?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I know how to change the cell color for a duplicated entry, but how/can I change the color on every 4th entry? Value will be an unknown number & letter combo, wanting to highlight every 4th time the same combo is entered.

Hey all, thank you for bearing with me, I have uploaded an example of what I would like the finished sheet to look like, link below.

I have manually highlighted the 4th repeat of the letter/number combo's C020, G020, B004 & F028

As you can see the repeats will not necessarily happen on the same row, or after 4 columns.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=56226468952646159686

Comment: Does it mean that the 5th repeat should not be highlighted? It should highlight 4 repeats then 8 repeats and so on?

Comment: Are you able to provide example data? Please take a look at [ask] and take our [tour] to learn how to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks pat2015, that is correct, 5th to 7th would not be highlighted, 8th would be and so on

Comment: What program are you using?  Have you looked at testing the row number to see if it's a multiple of 4?

Comment: Hi fixer1234 I am using Excel 2016, the relevant data is in the grayed out column, the repeat might not happen for 15 days/columns, it might happen on the 7th, or 10th etc. it is not uniform. At the moment we are using 2 Excel sheets open side by side and manually checking every entry to highlight the 4th event of the same data.

Comment: If you want to just highlight every 4th entry of repeats then a helper column and formula on that could help or may be testing row number for multiple of 4 as stated by fixer1234. However for every distinct 4th repeat if you want a different color, then it could get complex and might probably need a VBA (programming) solution.

Comment: Continued...e.g. 1,2,2,1,1,1(4th 1 so Red),2,3,2(4th 2 so Red) and so on. But if you want one color for 4th 1 and another for 4th 2 then it's complex. Please detail out your question.Edit it to provide more information,possible sample data and expected outcome. Also do add any approach or formula that you may have tried so far that did not work.

Comment: Thank you pat2015 I will research helper columns and have edited the original question with more detail.

Comment: Also do you want it across the columns? e.g. Columns C E  G & I i.e. say entry B004 occurs 3 times in Col C then 4th one appears in Col E (That should be highlighted) and so on?

Comment: Hi pat2015 entries should not repeat in the same column, if they have it is in error. (We use the duplicate rule to cross check that) Repeated entries will likely be in different rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand ***exactly*** what you want,
because the sample spreadsheet that you've provided
doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question. 
You say "the relevant data is in the grayed out column",
but I don't see any repeated values in the grayed out columns. 
Do you mean "RETURN", "RETURN/DC", "TOTAL" and "TOTAL/DC",
which are repeated exclusively in the **non-**grayed out columns?

But the data that you present in (confusing/unclear) narrative form
give me something to work with. 
I'll assume that the numbers are in Row 1. 
Start with the technique for detecting duplicated entries:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:B1,B1)
```

which counts the number of times the value in *this* cell
has appeared so far in the row, up to *and including* the current cell. 
This will be 1 for the first occurrence of a value,
and 2 or more for duplicates. 
But you don't want to test whether this count is greater than 1;
you want to test whether it's a multiple of 4. 
So test

```
=MOD(COUNTIF($A1:B1,B1),4)=0
```

Just use the above formula for your conditional format,
***starting with the second cell***.

In the below,

- Row 1 is your data (from the question),
  conditionally formatted based on the second formula above,
- Row 2 is the first formula above, and
- Row 3 is the second formula above.

[image: spreadsheet with OP's data]

So Row 2 shows the number of repetitions in Row 1,
and Row 3 shows the columns where Row 2 is a multiple of 4
(and those are the columns where Row 1 is colored).

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for your help, row one above looks closest to what I am after. I have posted a link in the original question above with the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, I suggest a solution that uses little bit of VBA UDF and a Helper Column.

A slight simplified sheet example is given below. The relevant data is in Columns C,E,G & I. To the right of each of these columns is a Helper Column that you may like to hide if desired.

[image]

First of all in your worksheet press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to access VBA Editor. Insert a Module from the Insert Menu and paste the following UDF (User Defined Function) Code into it.

```
Function prmarr(ParamArray arg()) As Variant

Dim arr1
cnt = 0

For i = LBound(arg) To UBound(arg)

cnt = cnt + arg(i).Rows.Count ' get total rows from all ranges

Next i

ReDim arr1(cnt)  ' re dim the array for those many total rows

cnt = 0  ' reuse the counter now

'create a one dimentional list of array from all of the above ranges
For i = LBound(arg) To UBound(arg)
    For Each cell In arg(i)
        arr1(cnt) = cell.Value
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Next cell
Next i

prmarr = arr1  ' pass this array as return parameter
End Function
```

Note it's very basic VBA code and that there are not any validations or error checking in the code. If you pass a horizontal array or overlapping arrays or multi dimensional arrays it could fail. It's assumed that you will only pass a column array to it to work correctly.

This function takes in a variable number of column array ranges and returns a one dimensional array that contains all the cell values from it that we will use to count the total number of occurrences of the current value since the starting cell from first column of data.

Since there's a VBA Code in your Excel, you need to save the file as .XLSM Macro Enabled Excel Worksheet.

In D1 put the following formula and Drag it down up to the intended rows.

```
=COUNTIF($C$1:C1,C1)
```

Now as you progress thru subsequent Helper Columns. Each Helper column requires a slight modification to the formula. Though the structure remains the same, the number of arguments increase.

In F2 put the following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. Excel will now enclose the formula in curly braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula. This step, creating an Array Formula is required else it will give wrong outcome.

```
=SUM(IF(prmarr(C$1:C$9,E$1:E1)=E1,1,0))
```

Understand this formula. You are passing C1:C9 and E$1:E1 as parameters to UDF i.e. Previous columns(s) + current column first value upto the test condition value and check if there's a match with current cell. If yes SUM will produce the total count of that value since start of first column. Drag it down up to the intended rows.

Similarly now the Array Formula formula in H1 becomes

```
=SUM(IF(prmarr(C$1:C$9,E$1:E$9,G$1:G1)=G1,1,0))
```

And so on.

Complete this for all the columns.

Now comes the Conditional Formatting part.

Select the very first cell i.e. C1 in this case.
Go to Conditional Formatting --> New Rule --> Use a Formula to determine which cells to format.

Now in the Rule put the following formula

```
=MOD(D1,4)=0
```

Select the background color of your choice and click OK to apply the formatting to cell C1.

Now while C1 is selected, double click on Format Painter and paint this formatting to all applicable data columns.

[image]

Note that.

- Excel might have a limit on how many parameters can be passed to a UDF. I am not too sure if and how it may apply if it's declared as `ParamArray as Variant`
- I suggest that you first test it in a test worksheet with sample data simulating various conditions to get a confirmation that this works as expected before applying it to your production sheet.
- If you still face any issues or if any errors are there do update here and I will try to fix it if time permits.